# LAN but no WAN acess

Tags: dns, dhcp

I have just moved and when I did I received a new DSL modem. I have set it up as a transparent bridge as I have an internal router. It is just like I had done before, except I got rid of my static IP. I changed my Ubuntu server to DHCP. I can access any system on the LAN and even ping them. I have no WAN access. I have three other windows machines on the system and they can all use the WAN. I have the following information:

`ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:2b:34:83:19:99  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::922b:34ff:fe83:1999/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3720 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2277376 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:315728 (315.7 KB)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0xa000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:340833 (340.8 KB)  TX bytes:340833 (340.8 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6a:6b:63:67:72:ce  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         APT             0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

ping LAN:

PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.666 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.652 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.608 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.622 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.608/0.637/0.666/0.023 ms

ping WAN:

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3022ms


/etc/resolv.conf shows:

**# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     **DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.1.1****


/etc/network/interfaces shows:

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Any help? I am really frustrated with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps I would take:

- Check the output of `iptables -L` to ensure you aren't firewalling.
- Ping `APT` which appears to be your router (192.168.1.1).
- If you have `traceroute` or `mtr` installed try using it to find out where your are blocked.  I use `mtr -ni5 8.8.8.8`.
- Check DNS with a command like `host google.com`.
- Check `/etc/resolv.conf` to ensure it has reasonable data.